# What is parent directory of a process?

Tags: unix, process, parent, working-directory, lsof

In `lsof` output, it mentions 3 types of directories, cwd, rtd and pd. I understand cwd and rtd. But what is pd aka., parent directory for a process? I tried `lsof | grep ' pd '`, but I got no output. So none of the processes running in my machine now has that property set?

Comment: In the output of the `lsof` command, `pd` stands for **Parent Directory**. It's not common to see this in the output. It's possible that none of the processes running on your machine currently have this property set, which is why you're not seeing any output when you grep for ' pd '. If a process had this property set, it would appear in the `lsof` output.

Comment: @AyoubBensakhria I was asking **what** is a parent directory for a process. What is it used for? Like working directory is a directory to which the relative paths are compared or root directory is the root of the largest subtree that a process can access.